# PostgreSQL 12.3 stuck in recovery mode after server was not gracefully shutdown

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.3, I got this problem when the PostgreSQL service is running then the server shutdown immediately. After the server is running, PostgreSQL stuck in recovery mode.

The log file show this message "The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory."

Previously, when I used PostgreSQL 9.6, this error did not occur.

Anyone have the same experience or solution? Plese help about this problem.

Comment: This is normal, just wait. If you see unexpected messages in the log file, add them to the question. What is the setting of `checkpoint_timeout` and `max_wal_size`?

Comment: The log file show this message "The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory."

The setting of checkpoint_timeout is disable and max_wal_size = 4GB

Comment: Please add additional information to the question using [edit]. That is the message from the crash; the interesting messages would be from startup.